# Proving surjectivity in the following question.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, summation, proof-explanation, vector-space-isomorphism

The question is given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

The onto part is not clear for me. Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: What exactly is not clear? And where is this coming from?

Comment: It is from Jonathan S. Golan "The Linear Algebra a beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know" , why I am sure that there exists $v$ such that $\alpha (v) = \delta_{v}$ @darijgrinberg

Comment: I would suggest changing the title to "Proving Surjectivity" or something similar. "1-1" means "injective," and that's not the part you're asking about, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I changed it thank you @Annapox

Comment: If $D(V)$ is the dual space of $V$, then since a linear functional $\lambda \in D(V)$ is determined by its action on the basis $\{1, X, X^2, \cdots\}$, it suffices to find $b_1, b_2, \cdots$ such that $\delta_v(x^n) = \lambda(x^n)$.

Comment: And how can I find them @Riley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in D(V)$ be a linear functional on $V = \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Then $\lambda$ is determined by its action on the basis $\{1, X, X^2, \cdots\}$. Since $\delta_v(X^n) = n!b_{n+1}$, all you need is that 
$$ n!b_{n+1} = \lambda(X^n),$$
i.e. $b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n!}\lambda(X^n)$, i.e. if $v = (\frac{1}{n!}\lambda(X^n))_{n \geq 0}$ then $\delta_v = \lambda$.

Comment: why you were in need to define $v$ using the linear functional $\lambda$? why not directly defining it using $\delta_{v}$?

Comment: If you want to show surjectivity of the map $\mathbb{Q}^\infty \ni v \mapsto \delta_v \in D(V)$, then you want to show if $\lambda \in D(V)$ then there exists $v \in \mathbb{Q}^\infty$ such that $\alpha(v) = \delta_v = \lambda$. So we fix $\lambda$ and define $v$ such that $\delta_v = \lambda$. Does that help? This should justify why $v$ depends on $\lambda$ and this might answer your second question. (I think you're trying to say why can't we directly show $\lambda$ is "some" $\delta_v$. But this argument is trying to do exactly that.)

Comment: yes it helps thank you very much! :)